# Adding checkboxes to checkbox group -> listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox group to which I now add checkboxes at runtime.
The problem is my change listener, which is defined on the checkboxgroup.
It is not fired when the new checkboxes are checked - but it is when the old ones are.
(Furthermore, it is not fired when new checkboxes are added - although the new checkboxes are created `checked:true`)

So I want to add the change listener, which is defined on the checkboxgroup in variable `me`, to all child checkboxes. I think this has to be the way Ext does it, right?

```
newItems.push(Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox',Ext.applyIf(Ext.clone(me.defaults),{
    boxLabel : someString,
    name : someString,
    inputValue : someString,
    checked : true,
    listeners : {
        change: me.on('change');
    }
})));
```

But I am unsure how to achieve my goal (in the third-to-last-line), that the change event for the checkboxgroup is fired whenever the change event is fired for the checkbox.

Comment: Should not `change: me.on('change');` be like `change : function () { me.on('change'); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
change:function() { me.fireEvent('change'); }
```

would fire the change event on the checkbox group whenever the change event on the checkbox is triggered.